# What is the default color of 'option' Hover in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, hover

I have a custom dropdown menu with multi-checkbox capabilities and I would like to match the hover color of the options to the default option hover color for Chrome. Does anyone know where I can find this color value OR programmatically make it always match?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i have a custom dropdown multi select menu and when I hover over the "options" I want the background color to match the default Chrome background color when you hover over standard html 'option' elements. I know how to do it, just need to find out what that color is.

Answer (score 0):

## want manually find it by yourself? (new answer)

I came across a great tool called Browserling.com. You can try out any browser on any device without having to download anything. They have a ton of emulators so you can see how your site looks on all kinds of devices.

https://browserling.com

To obtain the color, first snap a screenshot of the choice menu in its open state. Then, use the color picker in Photoshop, Figma, or any online application (I believe you can find it like this https://imagecolorpicker.com/  by a simple google search) to select the color and obtain the incredibly accurate hex and RGB value color code for the pixel blue. hope is useful to you

---

## in my case (old answer)

the blue color data:

[image]

---

the bg remains white from what I see, only the border changes

[image]

here is a gif of how it looks on chrome,

example from here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp

---

**results**

**- on hover**

the border color becomes

`#4f4f4f` or `rgb(79, 79, 79)` or `hsl(0, 0%, 31%)`

[image]

[image]

**- normally without hover**

`#767676` or `rgb(118, 118, 118)` or `hsl(0, 0%, 46%)`

---

Comment: thank you for your answer but the color i'm looking for is the blue color when hovering over options from the menu.

Comment: @sychordCoder ah ok, its `#1e90ff` or `rgb(30, 144, 255)` or `hsl(210, 100%, 56%)`

Comment: thank you. As a side note, is there a way to make sure it always matches depending on the OS the user is on? Windows vs Mac etc.

Comment: @sychordCoder ah yes, I found a solution for you... use an professional web emulator . the best one is https://www.browserling.com/, you have every browser, every version, every OS. try there

Comment: and create a sample simple html with OPTION code in a codepen or fiddle and put the link in the browserling.com, and test in chrome windows and chrome ios, and chrome old vs new, ios old vs new... safari old vs new, and whatever other browser you want to gain the color from it. window 7 vs windows 10, vs windows xp.... also android or ios. you have freedom, I hope the tool help you

Comment: to gain the color first take a screenshot of the <option> menu opened, then go to photoshop or figma or whatever online tool (I think you can find it) and use the color picker to pick the color of the pixel blue

Comment: @sychordCoder see new answer